# Can we add primary key to collection datatypes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

When I tried to retrieve table using contains keyword it prompts `"Cannot use CONTAINS relation on non collection column col1"` but when I tried to create table using

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int,address map<text, int>,mail list<text>,phone set<int>,primary key (id,address,mail,phone));
```

it prompts `"Invalid collection type for PRIMARY KEY component phone"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the basics in Cassandra is that you can't modify primary keys. Always keep that in mind.

You can't use a collection as primary key unless it is frozen, meaning you can't modify it.

This will work

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int,address frozen<map<text, int>>,mail frozen<list<text>>,phone frozen<set<int>>,primary key (id,address,mail,phone));;
```

However, I think you should take a look at this document: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1

You can put secondary indexes on collections after cql 2.1. You may want to use that functionality.